# LightOpenID forbidden when redirecting back

Tags: php, openid, google-openid, lightopenid

I'm trying to use lightOpenID, which should be simple and a case of uploading the files then testing it works.
When I use the example-google.php I get click the login button, the first time it asked me to login to Google and allow/remember the site I'm building. Then it redirects back to example-google.php?login and a load of attributes. But that page says "Forbidden. You don't have permission to access path/to/folder/example-google.php on this server."
if I delete the attributes including ?login in the url, then I get the "Login with Google button" so clearly I do have file permissions correct.

If I click that button from now on it redirects me to the forbidden page right away, so clearly Google is remembering I'm logged in and happy with my site using the login.

I've rattled my brain over this, tried searching for help and all sorts. Any help is appreciated but I'm near the point of abandoning openid (because the other libs seemed more trouble to implement).

Comment: It seems to me that you have now solved your problem (at least it works for me when I try to log in on your website). What was the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching on this very issue, I got it to work. The issue is likely that your apache server or hosting provider's apache server has mod_security configured to block URLs in querystrings. My hosting provider is Hostgator, and all I did was ask them to whitelist my domains, and it stopped giving me the 403.

Comment: I found a similar answer elsewhere. My (shared) web host provider looked into it (they wanted an example URL where I had tried using OpenID). 

At one point they answered "The issue has been found in the firewall logs and we have submitted a bug report to the web application firewall developer. They will either issue a fix or provide a workaround.".
I just checked my e-mail now and they have fixed it.

Comment: Thanks @digitlworld, I had the exactly same error (and I'm also with Hostgator). It wouldn've been better if there was a better error message.

Comment: Is it possible to disable that particular mod_security behaviour via .htaccess? Ideally only for the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Use openid.php file. I have tried it, it redirects back successfully. You must be doing something wrong. Please state the problem in detail. Also, I can't access the link you have given here !

Comment: My new link is http://lightopenid.gastoncancino.com/ but I solved the problem, thanks anyway. Now I can log in my website.