# LightOpenID forbidden when redirecting back

Tags: php, openid, google-openid, lightopenid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LightOpenID forbidden when redirecting back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696234/lightopenid-forbidden-when-redirecting-back)

Please help:
I'm trying to use lightOpenID, which should be simple and a case of uploading the files then testing it works. When I use the example-google.php I get click the login button, the first time it asked me to login to Google and allow/remember the site I'm building. Then it redirects back to example-google.php?login and a load of attributes. But that page says "Forbidden. You don't have permission to access path/to/folder/example-google.php on this server."

My link example: http://www.gastoncancino.com/lightopenid-lightopenid-master/lightopenid-lightopenid/example-google.php

My mail is guido.gaston@gmail.com, please help me